# Laptop can't connect to internet: "destination port unreachable". What can cause it?

Tags: port, ethernet

One of our acer laptops suddenly can't connect to the internet through ethernet, although, it can reach the printer on the network. But pinging the default gateway or any external IP results in "destination port unreachable" error. Here are things that I've tried and did not work:

- reboot
- restart network controller
- disable firewall
- changing cable and connecting to the main switch directly
- ipconfig /release
- ipconfig /flushdns
- ipconfig /renew
- netsh int ip reset
- netsh winsock reset
- network reset
- switching DNS to Google's

Could it be possible that it's some hardware problem?

Comment: Output of `ipconfig /all` and `route print` would be interesting... [Edit] your answer to include it.

Comment: Already wipes windows and reinstalled it? Tries a Linuy Live cd?

Comment: No, not yet, I will try the Linux CD, and if all else fails, I will reinstall. But first, I'll remove some updates.